# Redirection to Organization Dashboard in Employer of Relationship

Tags: user-dashboard

When you create an Employer of relationship in Civicrm and the person who signs up on behalf of the Organization logs in he is usually redirected to his own dashboard. How do you redirect civicrm such that when he logs in he is redirected to the dashboard of the Organization?
Any help will be appreciated. I know that a redirect wil be implemented but what is the url of the organization dashboard?
Am using Civicrm 4.6.8 with wordpress 4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

No need to redirect.

1. Make sure that in the employee's Contact > Relationships tab that by Permissions it is checked that the Employee can View and Edit the Employer Contact.
2. When the Employee logs into their dashboard, scroll all the way to the bottom and you will see a Relationship section showing "employee" as Employee of "Employer". Over to the right you will see Edit Contact Information & Dashboard. This will allow you to access the "Employer" Dashboard.

Comment: My answer is based on CiviCRM 4.7.22